# Mysql: Use result from search as input for another search

Tags: mysql

Can you give some advice on how to use results from search to another search?!

I have a table like 
Table1

```
id | Country | City   | Amount 
---+---------+--------+------- 
 1 | US      | Dallas |     15 
 2 | US      | Dallas |     30 
 3 | US      | NY     |      7 
 4 | US      | Dallas |     11 
 5 | US      | NY     |     30 
 6 | US      | NY     |      1
```

I need to goup data by Country, City, and find first and last values: 
Table2

```
Country / City / first / last
--------------------------
US / NY / 7 / 1
US / Dallas / 15 / 11
```

I can group by country and city, but how i can use:

```
select * from table1 group by country, city
```

i can find first and last values when i know city:

```
select * from table1 where city='NY' order by ID limit 1;
select * from table1 where city='NY' order by ID DESC limit 1;
```

But how i can use values (NY and Dallas) as input for searches and have only one mysql query?!? :(

Comment: See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html) you are looking for `MIN()` and `MAX()`

Comment: thank you. I will check it :)

Comment: i see you writing queries like `select * from table1 group by country, city` i also suggest you to read how MySQL handles [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) it will show how you how to write a correct SQL query with `GROUP BY`.. And how [functional dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) works in MySQL.

Comment: sorry, i have edited my post... i actually need first and last values. But also i need to do all in one sql query... :(

Comment: SQL tables/resultsets are **orderless** by definition so there isn't a `first` or `last` in SQL terms.  We need to have a column which you can use to identify the order.. I assume the id column has a `PRIMARY KEY` with `AUTO_INCREMENT` option in your table?

Comment: Yes.  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) and   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: Raymond, thank you for your help. Your questions helped me to move on in correct direction!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
with cte0 as 
(
  select 
    min(id) min_id, 
    max(id) max_id 
  from x
  group by Country, City
)
select 
  x.Country,
  x.City,
  min(x.Amount) Last,
  max(x.Amount) First
from x
where x.id in (select min_id from cte0 union select max_id from cte0)
group by Country, City
```

Comment: Thank you for the query. I need to update db version. Current version does not support "with". I'll test the query later this month. But i had some ideas from your code and i got my query to work. Thank you!